# How to make text over an image responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have placed some text over an image, but as I change my screen size, the text moves out of the image and overflows. How can I fix the position of the text on that image irrespective of the screen size?

```css
.row {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.timeline_feed_image {
  position: relative;
}

.Image_text_Div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="timeline_feed_imagesDiv">
    <img class="timeline_feed_image" src="https://placehold.it/400" alt="">
    <div class="Image_text_Div">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</p>
      <p>It is a small world after all. Globalization is that great process
that #started perhaps with Mr. Marco Polo Globalizationis that great...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your text is not fitting into the container with specific screen size, you can control those screens using media query. i.e. reducing font-size, etc

Comment: Isn't there any other method to do the same?

Comment: Can you update your status? I'm happy to update my answer if it doesn't sufficiently answer your question, just let me know via a comment. Otherwise, please [accept](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you mean by responsive.

Responsive design means to adapt your site design to the size of the screen it is displayed on. The image size won't change however. Thus, your question appears to boil down to: how can I ensure that my text does not run out of the image?

One answer is: ensure that the container the text is in has the same size of the image, then ensure the text does not grow out of this container and hide any [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). Here is a demo of that.

```css
.row {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.timeline_feed_imagesDiv {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.Image_text_Div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: calc(100% - 14rem);
  padding: 3rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="timeline_feed_imagesDiv">
    <img class="timeline_feed_image" src="https://placehold.it/400" alt="">
    <div class="Image_text_Div">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</p>
      <p>It is a small world after all. Globalization is that great process
that #started perhaps with Mr. Marco Polo Globalizationis that great...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Key aspects of this approach:

1. The `.timeline_feed_imagesDiv` container is made to fit the image in it by a combination of

   - `display: inline-block`, making it so that the width of the container will now not equal its parent's width, but the width of its content, the image); and
   - `font-size: 0`, which will make it so that whitespace between the image and text `div` elements does not show and influence the size of the container.
2. The text is made to fit in the container by

   - setting a `max-height` that will restrict it to be in the `.timeline_feed_imagesDiv` container;
   - setting `box-sizing: border-box` so that the padding [is included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) while calculating the `max-height`;
   - hiding overflow with `overflow: hidden`.
3. Because of the `font-size: 0` hack, the font size needs to be reset in the text `div`. This is what `font-size: 1rem` is for.

You can change `overflow: hidden` to `overflow-y: auto` to have a scrollbar appear, instead of hiding the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add background-image in CSS here:

```
.Image_text_Div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/400");
}
```